# Upgrading from Python 2 to Python 3 using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Last year or so, I have installed Python using Anaconda without reading too much about it. Now, more and more I need newer versions of some libraries like Matplotlib, therefore I wanted to upgrade my Python. Before moving further, I would like to ask what is the best way to move forward for this process? My current setup is below:

```
Anaconda 2019.10 version
conda version : 4.8.3
conda-build version : 3.18.9
python version : 2.7.16.final.0
platform : win-64 / Windows 10
```

Official website of Anaconda suggests getting the newest version, but they are not specific, i.e. newest version of Anaconda or conda? Shall I do this from the command line or download the installer? Best way seems to be creating a new environment as well...

Many thanks!

Comment: Download the installer, it's the best way to avoid headaches. Whether to create a new environment or not hugely depends on how it's currently set up in your machine, but if I'm not mistaken Anaconda is smart enough to point itself towards the most recent Python version you have installed. Of course, you can also delete your current Python install if you really want to make sure things won't break.

Comment: This was my initial instinct as well, but I have read somewhere that if the Anaconda is already installed, then the new installer do not work. Didn't try my chances though!

Answer (score 0):

Updating your Anaconda will also update your conda. conda is the **package manager** whilst Anaconda is the **packages suite**, which includes conda.

You can launch, from the command line:

```
conda update --all
```

To update Anaconda.

As for switching to Python3, you can easily do so by creating a new environment in Anaconda, if you just need a temporary solution:

```
conda create --name py3 python=3.9
```

Then activate the environment

```
source activate py3
```

If you need to **permanently** update your Python in Anaconda, just go with:

```
conda update conda
```

And then install the desired Python

```
conda install python=3.9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't sure whether my version of conda is compatible with Python 3, because the official site explicitly says use Anaconda2 installer for Python 2 and use Anaconda3 installer for Python 3. Since I have Python 2 now, I thought I need to download the new installer...

Comment: AFAIK you don't need Anaconda 3 just to have Python3. I have updated my answer, hopefully that'll do for you